# Opposite "side" of a hose?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

When I want to describe the side(?) of a hose or any other round object, what is the appropriate word for it?
For example, when there is one drilled hole in a hose and I want someone to cut the opposite side of the hose completely, is it appropriate to use the word side since a hose has no sides. Can I say:

- Please cut the opposite side of the hose from the hole

I added pictures

[image: ribbed plastic tube with a line down it lengthwise]

↓This is what I want to do
[image: clear plastic tube with a cut lengthwise]

Comment: You certainly can talk about the opposite side of something round, for example you can talk about the opposite side of the moon. Regarding your sentence, I think you need a diagram to show what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean the opposite **end** of the hose? Like tens of meters away?

Comment: Draw a picture.  That's easier than words.

Comment: A hose has two sides -- inside and outside.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I could't describe what I wanted to say. I drew a picture.

Comment: So you want to slice the full length of the tube 180 degrees opposite from the hole so that in the resulting rectangular strip, the hole will be located along the midline?

Answer (score 0):

Edit After OP Added the 2nd Photo

To have the cut *right below the hole*, as in your comments, sounds as though the cut is on the same side as the hole, as @Kate Bunting commented.  This would not be what you want.  We could consider

> Please cut, opposite the hole, lengthwise throughout the hose so that the piece can be fully opened.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added another picture. I want to cut the hose so it can be opened and I want the cut to be right below the hole. So 'opposite side' is not appropriate in this situation?

Comment: I can't see clearly the 2nd photo, newly added after I submitted my answer.  This photo shows a complete cut such that the hose can be fully opened flat; something not mentioned earlier.  That's why I stated x centimetres, meant to be decided as you wish.  I don't know whether my downvote is due to this latest development or something else.  I am unable to answer further until there is clarity.

Comment: 'Right below' sounds as though it is on the _same_ side!

Comment: hi @Kate, I didn't say "right below".

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I want a complete cut. And I want to state the location of the cut as well, which is (I don't know how to properly describe it ...) the opposite side of where a hole is at.

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore - I know _you_ didn't, but the OP did!

Answer (score 0):

Cut through the hose wall along the pipe's entire length so the hose can be spread open. (Place the cut diametrically opposite the small hole.)

We refer to the "wall" of a hose, and it has a "wall thickness".

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't understand what the hose wall is about... We have to use the phrase "cut through" because a hose has thickness ?

Comment: Cut *through the hose wall*  (together with "so the hose can be spread open") indicates that the cut should be just deep enough to extend through  the wall thickness; you don't want to cut into or through the wall opposite.

Comment: See the abbreviation "Wall Thick." here at this supply site. Some of the tubing there has an embedded wire for strength, but you can ignore that. 
 All tubing and hose has a wall thickness. https://www.mcmaster.com/products/tubing/tubing~/static-control-soft-plastic-and-rubber-tubing-for-air-and-water/

Comment: Or just place the hole at your convenience after slitting the tube lengthwise. It seems simpler.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!!

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty  I was under the impression that the hole was already in place.